# Laravel não descriptografa o refresh_token enviando a requisição com angular 2

Tags: laravel-5.3, angular

Quando realizo a requisição para recuperar o token funciona, mas quando eu mando a a requisição grant type refresh_token o laravel não consegue descriptografar o refresh token.

Angular 2

```
let params = {
        client_id: this.params['client_id'],
        client_secret: this.params['client_secret'],
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: this.getRefreshToken()
    };
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post(OauthLoginEndPointUrl, this.utilService.queryBuilder(params),{headers:headers})
        .map(resullt => {
            this.handleData(resullt);
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

A requisição retorna

```
{"error":"invalid_request","message":"The refresh token is invalid.","hint":"Token is not linked to client"}
```

Comment: resolvi mandando a requisição como payload com o json direto sem utilizar a URLSearchParams do angular 2.

Comment: é conselhável que voce elabore uma resposta pra sua própria pergunta, assim pessoas com o mesmo problema podem encontrar a resposta mais facilmente. ;)